# Angularjs, javascript passing array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

hello any one can help me. How can i put the result from the get method in $scope.chat = [{}] variable. Thanks in advance.

```
app.controller('ChatCtrl', ["$scope","$http", function ($scope,$http) {
 $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'assets/controller/chat/messages.php'
                 }).then(
                    function(response1){
                        $scope.contents=response1.records;


     });

$scope.selfIdUser = 50223456;
$scope.otherIdUser = 50223457;
$scope.setOtherId = function (value) {
    $scope.otherIdUser = value;
};

var exampleDate = new Date().setTime(new Date().getTime() - 240000 * 60);                    

**$scope.chat = [{
    "user": "bok",
    "content": "test1",
    "idUser": 1,
    "idOther": 2
},{
    "user": "bok",
    "content": "test2",
    "idUser": 1,
    "idOther": 2
}];**   

$scope.sendMessage = function () {
    var newMessage = {
        "user": "Peter Clark",
        "avatar": "assets/images/avatar-1.jpg",
        "date": new Date(),
        "content": $scope.chatMessage,
        "idUser": $scope.selfIdUser,
        "idOther": $scope.otherIdUser
    };
    $scope.chat.push(newMessage);
    console.log(newMessage);
    $scope.chatMessage = '';

};
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm ok!

We have

```
$http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'assets/controller/chat/messages.php'
                 }).then(
                    function successCallback(response1){
                    alert(response1);// gives  [Object, Object]?
                    console.log(response1);//Gives many values?
                    alert(response1[0][0]);//should print 'test'
                    alert(response1[0]['content']);//same/diff
                        $scope.contents=response1.records;


     });
```

In the console it gives a lot of values, so the data must be there.

Sorry for the question-answers, but without testing I am blind, can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Am i doing the right here? $outp = "";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"idUser":"'.$rs["conversation_id"].'",';
 $outp .= '"content":"'.$rs["msg"].'",';
 $outp .= '"user":"'.$rs["CompleteName"].'",';
    $outp .= '"idOther":"'.$rs["to_id"].'"}';
}
$outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';
$conn->close();

echo($outp);

Comment: Did the new snippet give any output, we need to know if the data is inside the then(function(response1), if the alert(response1[0][0]);//should print 'test' is the right assumption I can figure more out.

Comment: Lol not quite, but I got the structure of you SQL and seems ok.. How was the responses from the alert and logs?

Comment: Think I found a mistake as I was reading the docs. You call an intend which means (we try and you wont know when we finish) this means we are trying to acces data which we have no idea is there or not(undefined). With the succesCallback() we make sure not to start the function until the data IS returned.  Meaning you where on track just ahead of the data..

Comment: i got a result from here alert(response1.records[0]['content']); //test   just clear my browser. then got it.

Comment: dud thanks... i got, from the first comment you made.

Comment: Well, thank you very much, this is my first answer, juhuuu!!! I would still use the succesCallback just to make sure the array is returned.. BUT all you need now is looping through the array and pushing it into the $scope..Congrats